# Python and "re"

Tags: python, regex

A tutorial I have on Regex in python explains how to use the re module in python, I wanted to grab the URL out of an A tag so knowing Regex I wrote the correct expression and tested it in my regex testing app of choice and ensured it worked. When placed into python it failed:

```
result = re.match("a_regex_of_pure_awesomeness", "a string containing the awesomeness")
# result is None`
```

After much head scratching I found out the issue, it automatically expects your pattern to be at the start of the string. I have found a fix but I would like to know how to change:

```
regex = ".*(a_regex_of_pure_awesomeness)"
```

into

```
regex = "a_regex_of_pure_awesomeness"
```

Okay, it's a standard URL regex but I wanted to avoid any potential confusion about what I wanted to get rid of and possibly pretend to be funny.

Comment: You are probably being tripped up by the different methods re.search and re.match.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Python, there's a distinction between "match" and "search"; match only looks for the pattern at the start of the string, and search looks for the pattern starting at any location within the string.

[Python regex docs](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-re.html)
[Matching vs searching](http://docs.python.org/lib/matching-searching.html)

Answer (score 4):

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup 

soup = BeautifulSoup(your_html)
for a in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
    # do something with `a` w/ href attribute
    print a['href']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile("url")
>>> string = "   url"
>>> pattern.match(string)
>>> pattern.search(string)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb7f7a6e8>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the `re.match()` or `re.search()` method? My understanding is that `re.match()` assumes a "`^`" at the beginning of your expression and will only search at the beginning of the text, while `re.search()` acts more like the Perl regular expressions and will only match the beginning of the text if you include a "`^`" at the beginning of your expression. Hope that helps.